# Collect laravel events before dispatch and then dispatch only one event for a similar properties

Tags: laravel

Laravel Events
There will be case where many models belong to a object like Car. Though Car itself is model, it can have other different name models too which describes about Car. The reason for doing this is to split the big table into specific different tables.

Lets say, I want to create a event when any properties change related to Car object which means different models have different events created. But I want to dispatch only one event as long as the changes are related to Car but doesn't matter about from which model event created.

How can we achieve this?

Really appreciate your ideas and time devoted.

I still haven't found yet the valid idea to solve the problem

Comment: Could you say, 
`
$car->make->model->parts->engine 
$car->make->model->parts->tires
$car->make->model->parts->body
$car->make->model->years...
`
Each of those are dependent on each other so a make has a model, model has parts, parts have type_of_parts, etc..? then you have a Table of instance car that is a lookup table of model make year configuration of parts, if you want it unique. it sounds like you want a bunch of has one or belongs to relationships to better normalize the database into atomic tables that are not wide. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one